# Django does not want to include models in migration - PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-2.7, django-models

I have quite a specific problem, with django-admin.py not creating tables for model in the application directory. I have created a PostgreSQL database, and user, then granted this user all Privileges on the database, then included this database in settings.py. The relevant section of settings.py looks like below:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE':    'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME':      'crawler',
    'USER':      'austinpowers',
    'PASSWORD':  '****',
    'HOST':      'localhost',
    'PORT':      ''
    }
}
```

Django is able to access this database, as manage.py dbshell works well.

Now i want Django to create tables based on following models.py file of application "crawler":

```
from django.db import models


class Files(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=False, null=False)  
    filename = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.filename

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'File'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Files'


class IpLog(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=False, null=False)  
    ip = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    time_changed = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.time_changed

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'IP Log'
        verbose_name_plural = 'IP Logs'


class Jobs(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=False, null=False)  
    run_no = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    shop = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    pzn = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.shop + ": " + self.pzn

    class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Jobs'
    verbose_name = 'Job'
```

So I make sure "migrations" folder in "crawler" app subdirectory is empty, the database is empty, and then call:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

.. what leads to following output:

```
No changes detected
```

So I want to force Django to create initial migrations for application "crawler" by running:

```
python manage.py makemigrations crawler --empty
```

... what outputs:

```
Migrations for 'crawler':
  crawler/migrations/0001_initial.py:
```

However, when I want to see the contents of the migration file /crawler/migrations/0001_initial.py, I get an empty migration file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.10.4 on 2016-12-15 13:25
from __future__ import unicode_literals

    from django.db import migrations


    class Migration(migrations.Migration):

        dependencies = [
        ]

        operations = [
        ]
```

What suggests, that Django does not want for some reason, to create corresponding tables for models in models.py.

Indeed, when i call ...

```
python manage.py migrate
```

... I get the following output:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, crawler, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying crawler.0001_initial... OK
```

And the tables for my models are not present in the database.

Do you know, how can I force Django to create the tables? 
Django version used is 1.10.4

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is your `crawler` app in the list of `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: On top of what @chris pointed out, use command `python manage.py migrate` to apply migration changes to db.

Comment: @VikashSingh: Isn't OP already doing that?

Comment: @Chris Yes it is.

Comment: @VikashSingh as I have written above, I call this command.

Comment: @Chris: If it wasn't then `python manage.py makemigrations crawler --empty` wouldn't have worked I guess.

Comment: @AKS, I'd guess so too, but thought it was worth asking.

Comment: @PawełSopel can you show your `settings.py` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up data migrations and schema migrations. The [--empty](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/) flag is used in data migrations specifically to create an **empty migration** file, so that you can put your custom migration commands to produce a data migration.

In your case you don't have data. So the correct command is

```
 python manage.py makemigrations crawler
```

Followed by

```
 python manage.py migrate
```

**Update**:
Note that the very first time you run migrations on a newly created app, you need to explicitly mention the app name. *Merely doing ./manage.py makemigrations often does not work*. Which is what happened the first time you ran it without the app name.

Comment: As OP has mentioned: `python manage.py makemigrations` leads to `No changes detected`?

Comment: @AKS, the OPs command was `python manage.py makemigrations --empty`

Comment: Is it so? Please check again from top ;-)

Comment: @e4c5 Yes, update is good enough :). Though I would like to know why it often doesn't work on new apps?

Comment: @AKS, that part I never figure out either!! :-)

Comment: Yes, but i have to wait some time before i can do so :) Thanks a lot for your assistance!